# Integral of non-singular cosine apparently doesn't converge

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convergence

After running the following code I get an error that simple integrals are not converging. I make a false assumption that e>0, and proceed to evaluate the integral over e. Mathematica doesn't acknowledge the false assumption but strangely asserts that the integral diverges. The same error occurs if I integrate over `e.{1,0,0}`.

Aslo, when I now evaluate the same integral over a different variable, it gives the same error. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue - see [**`screenshot`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91u4u.png). I am using version 12 on a mac. However, the hint is that when you reset the kernel everything is fine. Which means, that `x` and the other variables you used were probably defined previously and leading to peculiar situations

Comment: Also, in the future, please refrain from using the `bugs` tag before receiving confirmation that is indeed a bug. You can, of course, use it on the title and say that you suspect a bug, but the tag is reserved for confirmed cases. This is the standard guideline for maintenance reasons :-)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue? If yes, can you share the reproduction steps? Otherwise, it will be very difficult to help

Comment: It is very difficult for me to do so, this occurred after about 2 pages of code. However, it seems to happen when I initiate with the assumption that x>0, and doesn't happen without this assumption. I will try and simplify down to something reasonable.

Comment: @MattMajic please make sure that after two pages of coding, `x` is clear and not pre-difned. If it's clear, it should be blue when you type `x` and in the expression `Integrate[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}]` it should be something between green and blue. Let's call it green/blue.

Comment: Lucas Lang, I have edited accordingly with a minimal working example.

Comment: The color of undefined variables is a bit hard to see, but you can change it in Preferences

Comment: @bmf, I believe x is undefined, and appears green/blue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I think to the situation. I am attaching a screenshot; see below

[image: screen]

Observe that the problem arose when the condition was `e > 0` but the two elements of the list were zero; please see below

[image: final]

Comment: While the exact error message is strange, it's not really surprising that something breaks if you provide assumptions that are effectively false (anything can be proven if you start with wrong assumptions). Honestly, I am surprised that `e>=0` works at all since comparison operators are not listable in Mathematica (so `{1,2}>0` doesn't evaluate to anything)

Comment: @LukasLang, when giving assumptions, many operators actually become "listable" (because you can provide the same assumption for many variables), for example: ``Simplify[Re[a] + Re[b], Assumptions -> {a, b} > 0]`` or ``Simplify[Re[a] + Re[b], Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals]`` both work as expected.

Comment: @LukasLang I agree that it is strange as a message, but the point is that caution is needed and also see the comment made by Domen

Comment: In addition to what @Domen wrote please also have a look at `GreaterThan[0] /@ {1, 2}` for general purposes :-)

Comment: Ofcourse removing the assumption e>0 "solves" the problem of not being able to do the integral. But the more serious problems are that assuming e>0 did not produce a relevant error message, while the given error message makes no sense, and that I cannot even evaluate the integral of cos(x) afterwards (when no assumptions on x were made).

Comment: @MattMajic very respectfully, I think you are missing the point. Perhaps did not see the screenshot carefully(?) With the assumption `x>0` ,`Integrate[e,{x,0,Pi/2}]` evaluates. With the correct assumption on `e` which is `e $\geq$ 0` again `Integrate[e,{x,0,Pi/2}]` evaluates. With the assumption `Cos[x]>0` again `Integrate[e,{x,0,Pi/2}]`  evaluates. It is only when you use the **WRONG** assumption on `e` that it gives an error.

Comment: See also the comment by @LukasLang

Comment: A side note: giving false assumptions does generate a warning, for example: ``$Assumptions = 0 > 0``. However, when a "combined" assumption is given, such as ``$Assumptions = {0, 0} > 0``, there is no warning because the assumptions are not evaluated until needed (in ``Integrate`` or some other function).

Comment: @Domen thanks for extra explanation :-)

Comment: @bmf I know that this only occurs with an incorrect assumption, I could have produced that answer myself. Ideally I wouldn't make incorrect assumptions. However, with many assumptions and many lines of code, this gets very difficult to troubleshoot and find where the incorrect assumption is, if the error tells you something different. I guess Mathematica just has some faults. But thanks Domen for the info, I will keep it in mind.